# How to get for every letter of sentence an index of letter?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, indexing

I want to get every letter and their index. But I got the wrong answer.

```
def counting(sentence):
    for letter in sentence:
        if not letter == ' ':
            print(letter ,":", [sentence.index(letter)],end ="    ")
print(counting("Hello my friends"))
H : [0]    e : [1]    l : [2]    l : [2]    o : [4]    m : [6]    y : [7]    f : [9]    r : [10]    i : [11]    e : [1]    n : [13]    d : [14]    s : [15]
```

I got this as an answer. The problem is that I got double e but with the same index. The idea is to get for example e:[1,19,24 etc.]. What should I change? Is a possibility to make it with dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `enumerate` to loop over the string and give both the element and also the index number.

This also uses a `defaultdict` in order to have a dictionary containing lists as values, where if the key does not already exist then it will be created as an empty list when you call `append`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

sentence = "Hello my friends"

indexes = defaultdict(list)

for index, letter in enumerate(sentence):
    if letter != ' ':
        indexes[letter].append(index)

for letter in sorted(indexes):
    print(f"{letter}: {indexes[letter]}")
```

This gives:

```
H: [0]
d: [14]
e: [1, 12]
f: [9]
i: [11]
l: [2, 3]
m: [6]
n: [13]
o: [4]
r: [10]
s: [15]
y: [7]
```

---

UPDATE: in response to a comment below saying that the output indexes should not increment on spaces: this is not my interpretation of the question, but if this is intended, it can be dealt with by pre-processing the input:

```
sentence = sentence.replace(" ", "")
```

(and then the `if` condition becomes unnecessary and could be removed).

Comment: Using `enumerate` gives the wrong output because it still will increment on spaces.

Comment: @BTables Yes, I think it is intended to do that. You still want the index number in the original string (so some index numbers are not present where there are spaces) - the question is about fixing the duplicates problem. But to answer the question based on your interpretation, you would just start with `sentence = sentence.replace(" ", "")` and then carry on without needing the `if` condition.

Comment: @BTables I have added an update to address your point - saying essentially what I said in my comment above - while also noting that I am not interpreting the question that way.

Comment: That's fair. Re-reading the question it does appear to be a little more open-ended than I assumed.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of searching for a letters index in-line, you can store matching positions in a list, and then that list in a dictionary.

```
def counting(sentence):
    output_dict = {}
    for i,l in enumerate(sentence):
        if l in output_dict.keys():
            output_dict[l].append(i)
        else:
            output_dict[l] = [i]
    return output_dict
for k,v in counting("Hello my friends"):
    print(f'{k}:{v}', end="    ")
```

Comment: Your explanation gives the value I didnt't want. I want to get a:[2,7] instead of a : [2], a :[7]

Comment: I got the same output. Maybe i do something wrong.

Comment: @Learningmachine sorry, I misread your question. Take a look at the edit, now.

Answer (score 0):

or you can do like this:

```
def counting(sentence):
    res = {key: [] for key in set(sentence)}
    for i in range(len(sentence)):
        if not sentence[i] == ' ':
            res[sentence[i]].append(i)
    return res
print(counting("Hello my friends"))
```